# Как убрать отступ у элемента <main>?

Tags: html, css

прошу помочь!
При вёрстке сайта по макету .xd возникла такая проблема: при создании элемента внутри main появляется отступ слева. При этом background применяется, но появляется скролл именно из-за этого самого отступа. По css-коду можете увидеть, как я при помощи margin пытался опытным путем убрать данный косяк, соответственно, ничего не вышло. Как мне исправить эту проблему? заранее благодарен!

```css
.bg{
    background:         #222020;
}

.navbar {
    overflow:           hidden;
    background-color:   #000000;
    position:           fixed;
    top:                0;
    left:               0;
    width:              100%;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    color:              #676767;
    cursor:             wait;
}

.nav1 {
    float:              left;
    color:              #ffffff;
    padding:            5% 2% 2% 0;
    text-decoration:    none;
    margin-left:        6%;
    font-family:        'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size:          130%;
}

.nav2{
    float:              left;
    color:              #ffffff;
    padding:            5% 2% 2% 2%;
    text-decoration:    none;
    font-family:        'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size:          130%;
}

.navLogo{
    float:              left;
    color:              #ffffff;
    padding:            4.5% 0 0 0;
    text-decoration:    none;
    font-family:        'Orbitron', sans-serif;
    font-size:          170%;
    margin-left:        27%;
}

main{
    margin-top:         9%;
    margin-left:        0;
    margin-right:       0;
}

.divBackground{
    width:              100vw;
    background-image:   url(./images/dbbg.png);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="bg">
<head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&family=Orbitron:wght@800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>FeFlops | Intel Investing</title>
</head>
<body>

    <header class="navbar">
        <a href="#" class="nav1">Our Services</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav2">Our Team</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav2">Contacts</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav2">Partners</a>
        <a href="#" class="navLogo">FeFlops</a>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="divBackground">
        <p>lorem ipsum ebal v rot</p>
        </div>
    </main>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Отступ не появляется. Он уже там был у body. Причём отступ этот является "браузерным". Иначе говоря, вам необходимо стили браузера переопределить (сбросить) своими:

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
outline: none;
border: none;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

А так как вы указывали ширину элемента в "vw", что означает "ширина viewport" (ширина области просмотра), то он вышел за рамки html. Отсюда появляется горизонтальная прокрутка

Comment: А смысл сбрасывать outline и border у htm с body?

Comment: @OliverPatterson, справедливо подмечено. Из готового решения для * (всех элеметов) скопировал. Поправлю ответ